# How do I colorize a column in datagrid Livecode from a button?

Tags: colors, datagrid, styles, livecode

How do I colorize or change style for a column in datagrid Livecode from a button?
I tried something like this but no succeed.

*set the dgColumnColor [col4] of grp "DataGrid" to "red"*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no "dgColumnColor" property for a Data Grid.

A data grid is actually a collection of objects/groups assembled on the fly.
Each cell in a table has a field and each column in the table is a group of these fields. The group name of the column is the name you have given the column.

You can verify this in the message box with...

put the dgprops["columns"] of grp "datagrid 1"

Assuming the name of your column is "ColorMe" and the data grid is "datagrid 1" then you need a repeat loop to step, line by line, through the table and set the backcolor of the column group "ColorMe" to the color you want.

Place this loop in the script of the data grid and call it whenever the data grid is opened or refreshed.

There are many customisations that you can do on a data grid both using its published properties as well as understanding how they are constructed.

To make it easier there is a plugin "Data Grid Helper" which can do what you ask and much more. I can heartily recommend it.

see http://www.aslugontheroad.com/ourproducts/2-what-is-dgh